# Why isn't Backbone invoking a simple route [and its corresponding function]?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, express, routes, backbone-routing

Here is my Router:

```
var MyRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        Backbone.history.start({ pushState:true });
    },
    routes: {
        'hello' : 'sayHello'
    },
    sayHello: function(){
        alert('Saying hello');
    }
});
```

Notice, I'm using `{ pushState:true }` to provide URLs without hash fragments.

I'm also using a Node.js server to deal with routes:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.listen(3010);
```

When I navigate to the route `http://localhost:3010#hello` my browser changes it to `http://localhost:3010/hello` but it works fine. However, when I personally navigate to `http://localhost:3010/hello` I get an `Cannot GET /hello` error.

This probably has a simple answer but can any one shed some light on what I may be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you call url with `#` it will try to load backbone defined routes. But calling it directly like `http://localhost:3010/hello` is calling your express routes which you have not defined(even if pushstate is true you need to call your backbone routes with #)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add an express route to handle any url fragments

```
app.use('/*', function(req, res) {
   // send your backbone app
   req.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

Comment: Now I get an `TypeError: Object #<IncomingMessage> has no method 'sendFile'` error.

Comment: @Wilhelm I am not sure about the exact api, sorry it was `res.sendFile` http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.sendFile